# wp_login_url() returns relative URL instead of full URL

Tags: wordpress

Trying to debug an issue on my WordPress site where using wp_login_url() both in templates and emails doesn't return the full URL.

It returns "/login/" instead of "https://sitename.com/login"

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something changed your login url if your not getting **wp-login.php**.

Anyway you can add anything after your site url by using this function

`site_url('anything')`

for your url

`site_url(wp_login_url())`

or (I prefer this)

`site_url('login')`

Comment: Theme My Login plugin is what is changing the login URL but I can't figure out where or why it would be taking out the site URL. The issue is that it is in emails for password resets, etc. so there are a lot of places this impacts. It seems like the best option is to maybe write some kind of filter that checks wp_login_url and adds the site URL if it doesn't contain it?

Comment: yes you can add_filter to login_url and add the site_url at the first of that

Answer (score 0):

For adding filter to your login url , you can use this code (I don't suggest this way)

```
function filter_login_url( $login_url ) {
    return site_url( $login_url );
}
add_filter( 'login_url', 'filter_login_url', 10, 3 );
```